# Matrix and table in single SSRS Report was cutting of the report width based on the Matrix width

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, width

In My SSRS Report I have matrix which has 2 grouped columns, and in the same report I have 15 columns table under Matrix, The problem here is width of the report was cutting based on the Matrix columns, resulting in not able to see all columns in the table. If we re arrange the table and Matrix top and bottom of the report it is working fine. Do we have any suggestions if we have Matrix and Table, top and Down respectively in the Report

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting that matrix inside the rectangle object solved the problem